# Scrolling issue iframe ios

Tags: iframe, scroll, youtube, mobile-safari

I am working on page with embed videos (vimeo & youtube). I am experiencing a problem on mobile : when I try to scroll down, if the finger is on the iframe the page doesn't scroll. You have to put your fingers around the iframe to allow the page scrolling.

Any ideas to fix that ?

Hope this is clear enough, sorry can't send you the page it is on a password protected server...

In advance thanks,
Alex

Comment: Is this related to web development or iOS development (is this a website you're trying to make work on the iPhone or is it an app you made that does this)?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I have just change the tag. It is a mobile webpage and the issue is on iOs Safari

Answer (score 0):

On Mobile Safari, wrap your iframes inside a container div. From the container you can control the scrolling. You also must ad a class or id to the iframe to control its attributes. Set overflow and webkit overflow. However, iframes in Mobile Safari are notoriously buggy, and you may have to tap it a couple times to make it work. This is an example:

```
<style>
    #page_container {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        background: #ffd800;
        padding: 1em;
        position: relative;

    }

    #iframe_container {
        height: 800px;
        width: 70%;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #iframe {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>

<div id="page_container">
    <div id="iframe_container">
        <iframe id="iframe" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```